# mongoid multi parameter attributes problem with date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have been following the mongoid railscast and I am facing a multi parameter attributes problem when i add a new field  `field :published_on, :type => Date`

```
Article.find("4da14b1447640b14eb000002").published_on 
=> nil
```

but with `Article.find('4da14b1447640b14eb000002')`

```
=> published_on: nil, published_on(1i): "2011", published_on(2i): "6", published_on(3i): "10"
```

How do i get the desire output?

i know there is a temporary solution https://gist.github.com/315227

but the issue of this problem is closed and I have the latest 2.0.1 mongoid gem and yet the problem occur.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Modify your `Article` class so it looks like the one below.

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  ...
end
```

Comment: it is still the same ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > Article.first.published_on
 => nil

Comment: Existing articles need to be updated. Have you tried to create a new article and see if it works ?

Comment: It also works if you edit/update the record. My thanks as well Zaiste. You'd think this would be flagged in a more prominent way in the Mongoid docs...

Answer (score 5):

In case you're using Mongoid 4.0 - the `Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes` has been removed there.

If you need this functionality anyway you may take the classes from [this](http://roodyruby.tumblr.com/post/67651747866/multi-parameter-attributes-support-for-mongoid-4-0) blog.